# Shapeless and annotations

Tags: scala, annotations, shapeless

I would like to have some function applied to fields in a case class, that are annotated with `MyAnnotation`. The idea is to transform type `T` into its generic representation, extract annotations, zip, fold right (or left) to reconstruct a generic representation and finally get back to type `T`. I followed the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231348/how-to-use-shapeless-to-detect-field-type-annotation) and this [gist](https://gist.github.com/shengc/2b4052ed59419e86f36f48da35812634).

I'm using scala 2.11.12 and shapeless 2.3.3.

Hereafter is my code:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._

case class MyAnnotation(func: String) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

trait Modifier[T] {
  def modify(t: T): T
}

object Modifier {

  def apply[A: Modifier]: Modifier[A] = implicitly[Modifier[A]]

  def create[T](func: T => T): Modifier[T] = new Modifier[T] { override def modify(t: T): T = func(t) }

  private def id[T](t: T) = t

  implicit val stringModifier: Modifier[String] = create(id)

  implicit val booleanModifier: Modifier[Boolean] = create(id)

  implicit val byteModifier: Modifier[Byte] = create(id)

  implicit val charModifier: Modifier[Char] = create(id)

  implicit val doubleModifier: Modifier[Double] = create(id)

  implicit val floatModifier: Modifier[Float] = create(id)

  implicit val intModifier: Modifier[Int] = create(id)

  implicit val longModifier: Modifier[Long] = create(id)

  implicit val shortModifier: Modifier[Short] = create(id)

  implicit val hnilModifier: Modifier[HNil] = create(id)

  implicit def hlistModifier[H, T <: HList, AL <: HList](
    implicit
    hser: Lazy[Modifier[H]],
    tser: Modifier[T]
  ): Modifier[H :: T] = new Modifier[H :: T] {
    override def modify(ht: H :: T): H :: T = {
      ht match {
        case h :: t =>
          hser.value.modify(h) :: tser.modify(t)
      }
    }
  }

  implicit val cnilModifier: Modifier[CNil] = create(id)

  implicit def coproductModifier[L, R <: Coproduct](
    implicit
    lser: Lazy[Modifier[L]],
    rser: Modifier[R]
  ): Modifier[L :+: R] = new Modifier[L :+: R] {
    override def modify(t: L :+: R): L :+: R = t match {
      case Inl(l) => Inl(lser.value.modify(l))
      case Inr(r) => Inr(rser.modify(r))
    }
  }

  object Collector extends Poly2 {
    implicit def myCase[ACC <: HList, E] = at[(E, Option[MyAnnotation]), ACC] {
      case ((e, None), acc) => e :: acc
      case ((e, Some(MyAnnotation(func))), acc) => {
        println(func)
        e :: acc
      }
    }
  }

  implicit def genericModifier[T, HL <: HList, AL <: HList, ZL <: HList](
    implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[T, HL],
    ser: Lazy[Modifier[HL]],
    annots: Annotations.Aux[MyAnnotation, T, AL],
    zip: Zip.Aux[HL :: AL :: HNil, ZL],
    rightFolder: RightFolder[ZL, HNil.type, Collector.type]
  ): Modifier[T] = new Modifier[T] {
    override def modify(t: T): T = {
      val generic = gen.to(t)
      println(generic)
      val annotations = annots()
      println(annotations)
      val zipped = zip(generic :: annotations :: HNil)
      println(zipped)
      val modified = zipped.foldRight(HNil)(Collector)
      println(modified)

      val typed = gen.from(generic) // temporary
      typed
    }
  }
}
```

The code above compiles. However, when instanciating a `Modifier` in a test:

```
  case class Test(a: String, @MyAnnotation("sha1") b: String)

  val test = Test("A", "B")
  val modifier: Modifier[Test] = implicitly
```

the test file does not compile and give the following error:

```
  [error] ambiguous implicit values:
  [error]  both value StringCanBuildFrom in object Predef of type => 
           scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]
  [error]  and method $conforms in object Predef of type [A]=> <:<[A,A]
  [error]  match expected type T
  [error]       val ser1: Modifier[Test] = implicitly
```

The problem seems to come from the right folder definition: when removing `rightFolder` from the list of implicits in `genericModifier`, then it works:

```
  implicit def genericModifier[T, HL <: HList, AL <: HList, ZL <: HList](
    implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[T, HL],
    ser: Lazy[Modifier[HL]],
    annots: Annotations.Aux[MyAnnotation, T, AL],
    zip: Zip.Aux[HL :: AL :: HNil, ZL]/*,
    rightFolder: RightFolder[ZL, HNil.type, Collector.type]*/
  ): Modifier[T] = new Modifier[T] {
    override def modify(t: T): T = {
      val generic = gen.to(t)
      println(generic)
      val annotations = annots()
      println(annotations)
      val zipped = zip(generic :: annotations :: HNil)
      println(zipped)
      /*val modified = zipped.foldRight(HNil)(Collector)
      println(modified)*/

      val typed = gen.from(generic) // temporary
      typed
    }
  }
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your code seems to miss too many pieces to be a [mcve]. Particularly there is a confusion between `MyAnnotation`, `PII` and the fact that both declarations are missing. I think you should fix that if you want to get some answers.

Comment: @SergGr thanks for spotting this. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Sorry, this is still not a [mcve]. Could you actually try to compile your code as it is presented in the question? Here are some more obvious issues: `Modifier` definition is still missing; as @DmytroMitin said in his answer, your `genericModifier` fails to compile despite you claiming otherwise. There are probably more. If you are not satisfies with Dmytro's answer, please make sure you really post an [mcve]. An easy way to verify that is that you can copy-paste that to https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ and get the same behavior as you claim it to be.

Comment: @SergGr I tried using scastie.scala-lang.org but it fails to pull dependency com.chuusai:shadedshapeless_2.11:2.3.3. I modified the first block of code with a complete example that compiles locally in my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code:

- defining `Poly` just for `Option` is too rough (pattern matching is performed at runtime and compiler should know definitions for `Some` and `None` at compile time)
- `HNil` should be instead of `HNil.type` and `HNil : HNil` instead of `HNil` (types `HNil` and `HNil.type` are different)
- compiler doesn't know that `RightFolder` actually returns the original `HList` type, so you should use `RightFolder.Aux` type.

Correct code is

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{RightFolder, Zip}
import shapeless.{::, Annotations, Generic, HList, HNil, Lazy, Poly2}
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

object App {
  case class MyAnnotation(func: String) extends StaticAnnotation

  object Collector extends Poly2 {
//    implicit def myCase[ACC <: HList, E] = at[(E, Option[PII]), ACC] {
//      case ((e, None), acc) => e :: acc
//      case ((e, Some(MyAnnotation(func))), acc) => {
//        println(func)
//        e :: acc
//      }
//    }

    implicit def someCase[ACC <: HList, E]: Case.Aux[(E, Some[MyAnnotation]), ACC, E :: ACC] = at {
      case ((e, Some(MyAnnotation(func))), acc) =>
        println(func)
        e :: acc
    }

    implicit def noneCase[ACC <: HList, E]: Case.Aux[(E, None.type), ACC, E :: ACC] = at {
      case ((e, None), acc) => e :: acc
    }
  }

  trait Modifier[T] {
    def modify(t: T): T
  }

  implicit def hListModifier[HL <: HList]: Modifier[HL] = identity(_) 
  // added as an example, you should replace this with your Modifier for HList

  implicit def genericModifier[T, HL <: HList, AL <: HList, ZL <: HList](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[T, HL],
    ser: Lazy[Modifier[HL]],
    annots: Annotations.Aux[MyAnnotation, T, AL],
    zip: Zip.Aux[HL :: AL :: HNil, ZL],
    rightFolder: RightFolder.Aux[ZL, HNil/*.type*/, Collector.type, HL /*added*/]
    ): Modifier[T] = new Modifier[T] {
    override def modify(t: T): T = {
      val generic = gen.to(t)
      println(generic)
      val annotations = annots()
      println(annotations)
      val zipped = zip(generic :: annotations :: HNil)
      println(zipped)
      val modified = zipped.foldRight(HNil : HNil /*added*/)(Collector)
      println(modified)

      val typed = gen.from(modified)
      typed
    }
  }

  case class Test(a: String, @MyAnnotation("sha1") b: String)

  val test = Test("A", "B")
  val modifier: Modifier[Test] = implicitly[Modifier[Test]]

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val test1 = modifier.modify(test) // prints "sha1"
    println(test1) // Test(A,B)
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank very very much!

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin, the above code does not work when the annotation class has multiple argument and they are not given in true order. I am trying to do exactly what is asked here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232750/is-there-a-way-to-find-arg-values-reliably-from-case-class-which-is-used-as-anno) . I would appreciate if the answer is given to this question