# Using Option and strings instead of Some in code

Tags: scala, null

I've seen a lot of times code like this:

```scala
...
val aString: String = someFunctionDataReturnsAString()
...
if (someCondition) Some(aString)
else 
...
```

Is it right to create a new `Option` using `Some(aString)`?
What if for some reason turns out the value of `aString` is `null`?
Wouldn't be good replacing the `if` sentence with:

```scala
if (someCondition) Option(aString)
```

Because:

```scala
val a = Some("hello")
val b: String = null
val c = Some(b)
val d = Option(b)
println(a)
println(c)
println(d)
```

Will print in the console:

```
Some(hello)
Some(null)
None
```

Looks like a better idea to use `Option` when passing a string as parameter, so in case the string is `null` the value of the `Option` will be `None`.

I've seen code to be reviewed and I think with cases like this a comment should be added asking for replacing `Some(aString)` with `Option(aString)`.

Comment: Yeah, `Option` is better.

Answer (score 5):

You are right. Assuming your string can be null, it's recommended to use [`Option(aString)`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/Option$.html#apply%5BA%5D(x:A):Option%5BA%5D):

> `def apply[A](x: A): Option[A]`
>
> An `Option` factory which creates `Some(x)`
> if the argument is not `null`, and `None` if it is `null`.
>
> `x` - the value
>
> returns - `Some(value)` if `value != null`, `None` if `value == null`

Class [`Option`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/Option.html) mentions that both have their use case, so the programmer has the last say which one is better suited for his particular need:

> Interacting with code that can occasionally return null can be safely
> wrapped in `scala.Option` to become `None` and `scala.Some` otherwise.

On a personal note, since strings are immutable and you can't really have uninitialized strings (because Scala always requires you to initialize them - unless you use `var` variables, which is not the recommended way to program in Scala anyway), you'll rarely actually encounter null strings in your code.

That being said, one can still decide to go for `Option(aString)` every time, and it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Normally it's ok to replace `Some.apply` with `Option.apply` (and safer).

But, although normally this is not a big deal (and let's avoid premature optimizations), there can be minor runtime overhead for `Option.apply`, since we add another branching instead of just wrapping.

Generally, you could split your project into pure FP part (it's ok to assume that your strings are not `null` there and use `Some.apply`, also `Some.apply` is canonical [monadic](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monad.html) `pure` for `Option`) and part where you interact with the outer world, with Java libraries etc. (it's more safely to use `Option.apply` there).

But we should keep in mind that `Some.apply` returns `Some[A]` while `Option.apply` returns its supertype `Option[A]`. Normally it's ok but sometimes in [type-level](https://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/) calculations this can be too rough if you need to know precise type at [compile time](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html). See for example [Shapeless and annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412106/shapeless-and-annotations) , [how to use shapeless to detect field type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231348/how-to-use-shapeless-to-detect-field-type-annotation)

Comment: https://medium.com/@regis.leray/scala-cats-nice-tricks-and-fun-30b5cb97fab3